# Assigning the value of a remote variable to a local variable in unix/linux

Tags: unix

I am creating a remote variable whose value I want to assign to a local variable in unix. Here is the code
    #!/bin/bash

```
INPUT= "test"
ssh username@domain.com
"if [ -s $INPUT ];
then
    date=\`date\`
    remote= $INPUT.date
    $INPUT= \$remote
else
    mkdir $INPUT
fi"
```

Basically I am assigning a value to a local variable. Upon ssh to a remote server, I am checking whether a non-empty directory by the name of "test" exists. If it does, then I am appending a time-stamp to the $INPUT local variable. The code works fine till line 8 "remote= $INPUT.date". But the assignment of the remote variable \$remote to the local variable $INPUT does not. What am I doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think the remote shell can change your local shell's variables, no. Instead the script you run remotely could e.g. print the value of $remote or nothing, and you could e.g. capture this into a variable locally with backticks and then use that to conditionally update INPUT?

Comment: So how do I do this? Export the remote variable to a file locally? I tried "cat \$remote > file.txt" but file.txt gets made on the remote server, since the whole code ("if .... fi") is working on the server.

Answer (score 5):

As Rup said, the remote shell cannot set your local shell variables. You need to capture the remote variable by  printing it out, and using command substitution. This SSH command will do what you are trying to do, then it will echo the amended value you want to store in $INPUT:

```
INPUT="test"
ssh user@remotehost "if [ -s $INPUT ]; then 
timestamp=\$(date)
echo "${INPUT}.\${timestamp}"
fi"
```

Output:

```
test.Monday, 24 February 2014 11:26:41 GMT
```

If you want $INPUT to be changed, you then need to use the whole SSH command as a command substitution:

```
INPUT="test"
INPUT=$(ssh user@remotehost "if [ -s $INPUT ]; then 
timestamp=\$(date)
echo "${INPUT}.\${timestamp}"
fi")
```

Output:

```
$> echo $INPUT
test.Monday, 24 February 2014 11:27:47 GMT
```

Similarly, if you want to store a variable in a txt file, this will store it on the remote host:

```
ssh user@remotehost "echo \$remote > file.txt"
```

This will store it locally:

```
ssh user@remotehost "echo \$remote" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with:

```
SERVERS=('server1@host1' 'server2@host2' 'server3@host3')
for server in "${SERVERS[@]}"
do
       remoteVariable=$(ssh $server "echo \$remote")
       echo $remoteVariable
done
```