# sed: There is no file or directory on ssh bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sed

I want to save in a variable what the sed returns and then use it to compare with other text but when I try to save it I get this error.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: test.sh

IPS=$HOME/Documentos/ips.txt
VERSION=/var/www/html/games/game/version
EOF=/dev/null
PASSWORD='password'

while read -r IP; do
    echo $IP
    sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 $IP bash -c "'
    REVISION=$(sed -n -e 6p $VERSION)
    echo $REVISION
    '" < $EOF
done < $IPS
```

This is the output:

```
192.168.232.69
sed: can't read /var/www/html/games/game/version: There is no file or directory
192.168.191.20
sed: can't read /var/www/html/games/game/version: There is no file or directory
192.168.191.19
sed: can't read /var/www/html/games/game/version: There is no file or directory
```

It should be clarified that when I use the command without saving it I do not have any errors and the file exist in every terminal.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the command on the same server on which the error occurs? Since you're echoing the IPs, you should be able to see which server has the error - it will be the one whose IP address is printed immediately before the error message.

Comment: Are you sure the command works without saving? Run again the command to be sure: `sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 $IP bash -c "sed -n -e 6p $VERSION"`

Comment: You can also try to simply list the file. I bet that the command does not work and the file is not there: `sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 $IP bash -c "ls -l $VERSION"`

Comment: @RobinGreen yes, I'm sure but I forgot to post the ip.

Comment: @Poshi I did what you told me in the first comment and the result was this:

192.168.232.69
REVISION=59
192.168.191.20
REVISION=59
192.168.191.19
REVISION=59

The file exists, it is checked

Comment: Weird. It doesn't make any sense :-?

Comment: @Poshi I know, I'm fighting with this for days and I can not make it work. I already probe with awk, cat and neither. In ssh it does not save the variable, it must be something between the remote terminal and the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help, I solved it using this link:

[Assigning the value of a remote variable to a local variable in unix/linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977296/assigning-the-value-of-a-remote-variable-to-a-local-variable-in-unix-linux)

Comment: I don't understand. The link that solved your problem talks about assigning variables from inside an `ssh`to an outside var. It explains the difference between local and remote. But you had a different problem, one where `ls` would find a file but `sed` said there was no file. Cannot see the link :-(

Comment: @Poshi It couldn't find the file because it was looking for it in the local machine, so when I indicated that I had to look for it in the remote machine it saved the sed. There was always the file on the remote machine.

Comment: Oh! You are right! The process substitution occured before starting the ssh, so obvious now! XD Glad you solved it :-)